# How to prevent occurrence of or cause Excel to ignore all circular references in a spreadsheet automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have very large Excel spreadsheets. Excel recognizes a large number of cells as having circular references.  However these are not true circular references and I wish to avoid all these error messages without having to ignore or alter each of thousands of cells one by one. Can I prevent the Excel program from classifying these as errors or can I make Excel ignore all of them and allow me to use the formulas unhindered each time I open a spreadsheet or workbook.  I hope that the solution will not slow down the processing speed of the computer.

Comment: @Lance Roberts can you explain why the given answer does not work for you, given also [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/disable-circular-reference-help-app-pop-up-window/a3bc8891-9b37-49e4-8ddf-ebcadb56d5d8) which explains something more about it ?

Comment: @1NN, It may do, and I'm testing it now, but I'd like a way to disable that kind of error messages (and the Excel bugs that accompany them). In the options, you can disable many types of errors, but not that one. Hoping there is a way so I can stop the buggy lags and crashes.

Comment: @LanceRoberts why don't you just ENABLE cyclic calculations (as described in harrymc's answer). That's on application level. See also here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/remove-or-allow-a-circular-reference-8540bd0f-6e97-4483-bcf7-1b49cd50d123

Comment: @1NN, I was under the impression that it was a workbook-level setting. It's great if it's not, but I now find, by hovering over the 'Calculate' phrase in the status bar, that Excel says "Results of formulas may be out of date because Excel is not set to calculate automatically. Click here or press F9 to recalculate manually." If this really means what it says (which I'm doubting because I see calculations change) then that isn't functional. I'll have to observe more.

Answer (score 2):

The bounty asks for a way to totally disable circular references
messages inside the Excel application. There is no known hack or registry
item that can do that, so all I can suggest is a method for
immediately closing automatically the message whenever it appears.

This message is actually pretty important to have, because the option
"Enable iterative calculation" should not be enabled on risk of losing
the workbook in case of a data-entry error (unless you really depend on it).
See the article
[The Circuit Breaker – How to Fix Circular Reference Errors in Excel](https://www.adventuresincre.com/fix-circular-reference-errors-in-excel/)
for an example workbook that can be destroyed by typing one wrong
character and for the explanation of the problem, and even for a solution
(which is not easy to apply).

I use the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
to detect the dialog whenever it appears and close it immediately.

The following script will create a timer that will execute
every 200 milliseconds, check for the dialog, and close it if found.
This is a low-resource check that should not have a noticeable effect
on your performance

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, checkCircular, 200

checkCircular:
If WinExist("ahk_class #32770", "There are one or more circular references")
{
   WinClose
}
Return
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Note that if you have circular references in your workbook,
I would recommend finding and removing them.
This would be the best method for getting rid of this message.

Answer (score 1):

[This thread on mrexcel.com](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/hide-circular-references-warning-with-vba.362987/) gives a solution using a VBA Macro. Be aware that this will suppress any warning messages, not only those about circular references:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If errormsg Then SendKeys "{esc}", True End If

End Sub
```

For more details, check out [this tutorial on running a Macro on opening a workbook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44)

If you have the same problems while editing, you might also trigger a macro upon a specific cell range (adapted [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/run-macro-cells-change)):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will suppress the warning
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

' When one of the designated cells has been changed 
        If errormsg Then SendKeys "{esc}", True End If

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'd like an answer that would stop it at the application level, instead of the workbook level, since I work in so many different old broken workbooks.

Comment: The problem with a bad circular reference is that it can totally block the spreadsheet, in effect killing it, and if a save is done by mistake it will require using a backup version. Suppressing the message is only cosmetic and won't revive such a spreadsheet, and may even lead to the fatal mistake of doing a save.

Answer (score 0):

If the spreadsheet contains cyclic formulas and you would like to disable
this calculation:

- Open menu *File > Options > Formulas*
- In the section "Calculation options":

  - Unchecking "Enable iterative calculation" will block
    calculations, and you will receive a one-time warning message
    (if there exist any circular references)
  - Alternatively, enable it but set a very low value for
    "Maximum Iterations"
- Click OK.

Comment: Actually, you have to ENABLE cyclic calculations to suppress excels warning message